# backbone.js: dynamic router for hash with a slash after it?

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, backbone-routing, jquery-1.9

I want to have the hash url like this,

```
site.com/#/page/edit/about-us/
```

so I set the router in my backbone,

```
routes: {
        '/page/edit/:url/':    'renderDynamicPage',
    },

    renderDynamicPage: function (url) {
        console.log(url);
    },
```

but nothing comes out.

it should be `about-us`

any ideas why and how I can get around to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Backbone.js documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Router-extend) says

> Note that you'll want to avoid using a leading slash

try

```
routes: {
        'page/edit/:url':    'renderDynamicPage',
    },

    renderDynamicPage: function (url) {
        console.log(url);
    },
```

Comment: yes it works in that way. backbone is not dynamic enough I guess!thanks.